# need to memset global strings or strings inside global structs

Tags: c

Do we need to `memset` global C style strings or is it initiated to `'\0'` on its own?

for example:

```
char c_string[10];
```

OR

```
struct node
{
     int   x;
     char  y[10];
};
```

Comment: Global (and static) variables, in the absence of a different initalizer, are initialized to `0` (recursively if needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File scope variables ("global") have *static storage duration*. All variables with static storage duration are automatically initialized to zero (or NULL).

However, relying on this initialization is bad practice - it is better to make a habit of writing

```
char c_string[10] = "";
```

even if that makes no practical difference. This is self-documenting code meaning that you have actually considered the zero-initialization, rather than `char c_string[10];` which could as well mean that you got it right by luck.

Comment: what about need to initialize variables declared inside `struct`?

Answer (score 2):

Global variables having arithmetic types (including `char`) are initialized to zero, so you don't use `memset()` for the first initialization.

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.7.9 Initialization 10:

> If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
> explicitly, then:
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
> and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
> rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;